# GWT Multiple sessions - Debug in Development Mode

Tags: java, gwt, eclipse-plugin, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I am trying to have multiple debug sessions from either multiple/same browser, I receive a blank screen.

For example, when I try `http://127.0.0.1:8888/browser.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` from different browser tabs. It just traces in eclipse as follows,

> Connection received from [source ip]. Opened [new port]

and sends a **EOF** and **favicon.ico**

Besides this, I can not even F5 (reload) on my browser. It is considered as a new connection and it simply sends me to a blank screen, once again.

Only the first browser session ever works.

```
GWT version: 2.5.0
Extjs GWT version: 2.2.5
```

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0 doesn't seem to explain a lot of multiple sessions.

Comment: I use different browsers at the same time without problems... but only one debug session per browser.